# triggering multiple events with single onClick

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a `iframe` on my web page. On anchor click a pdf file opens in the `iframe`. I have provided button by clicking which I close/display:none the `iframe`. I want the `iframe` to show again when the anchor is clicked. The click of the anchor should show the `iframe` and open the pdf in that `iframe`. Please help me how to do that.

I have tried the following:

```
function CloseWindow() {
var ifr = document.getElementById("ifrlyric") 
ifr.style.display='none' }

function OpenWindow() {
var ifro = document.getElememtById("ifrlyric")
if (ifro.style.display=='none') { ifro.style.display='block' }   }

<a href="#" onClick=" window.lyrics.location='mypage.pdf';  ifrlyric.style.display=block;   return false;">Mypage</a>
```

The anchor is opening the pdf in the `iframe` first time and the click button hides it. But again when the anchor is clicked the `iframe` is not showing.

Comment: Do not inline JS. By the way, why did you tagged this as jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a third function such as

```
function toggleState() {
    if(document.getElementById('ifrlyric').style.display == 'none') {
        window.lyrics.location='mypage.pdf'; // And I suggest moving this to OpenWindow
        OpenWindow ();
    } else {
        CloseWindow ();
    }
}
```

And then call it in your onClick :

```
<a href="#" onClick="toggleState();">Mypage</a>
```

**EDIT**

Re-reading your code I can see a typo, you wrote `getElememtById` instead of `getElementById`

Comment: I'd argue `toggleState` shouldn't rely on a base state

Comment: @Alexander You mean use `document.getElementById("ifrlyric").style.display` directly instead of a boolean toggle ?

Answer (score 0):

The function "OpenWindow" has the only mission to show the iframe, so I suggest to simply:

```
 function OpenWindow() {
    var ifro = document.getElememtById("ifrlyric")
     ifro.style.display='block'    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you tagged jquery, I'll say just use the jquery toggle function:

```
<a href="#" onClick="setLocation();">Mypage</a>

<script>
    function setLocation() {
        window.lyrics.location='mypage.pdf';
        $('#ifrlyric').toggle();
</script>
```

You didn't post enough code for me to know if this is exactly right, but it should at least be pretty close.